# iReport-5.6.0 открывается,но не запускается

Tags: intellij-idea, jasperreports

Пытаюсь запустить iReport-5.6.0. загрузка останавливается на этапе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит файл ireport.conf:

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/5.6.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/5.6.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999 "
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
jdkhome="C:\Users\tyuri\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.1"

# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

jdkhome взята из JDK home path из Intellij Idea. Ошибок никаких не выдается. Без понятия в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

А ну собственно, что я и находила в интернете. К сожалению, iReport-5.6.0 использует только jre7 ни больше, ни меньше. И да, потом в папке примерно C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.6.0\etc поменять владельца или разрешения пользователя на файл ireport.conf  и, открыв его в блокноте, указать jdkhome (путь к jre7) и убрать перед ним #.